# Creating a set from a variable instead of a file

Tags: python

I have a piece of code to read two files, convert them to sets, and then subtract one set from   the other. I would like to use a string variable (installedPackages) for "a" instead of a file. I would also like to write to a variable for "c".

```
a = open("/home/user/packages1.txt")
b = open("/home/user/packages.txt")
c = open("/home/user/unique.txt", "w")

for line in set(a) - set(b):
    c.write(line)

a.close()
b.close()
c.close()
```

I have tried the following and it does not work:

```
for line in set(installedPackages) - set(b):
```

I have tried to use StringIO, but I think I am using it improperly.

Here, finally, is how I have created `installedPackages`:

```
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
installedPackages = re.sub('\n$', '', re.sub('install$', '', re.sub('\t', '', stdout), 0,re.MULTILINE))
```

Sample of packages.txt:

```
humanity-icon-theme
hunspell-en-us
hwdata
hyphen-en-us
ibus
ibus-gtk
ibus-gtk3
ibus-pinyin
ibus-pinyin-db-android
ibus-table
```

Comment: so what is your exact question?

Comment: How can I read a set from a variable instead of a file?

Comment: You... you've just gone and scrapped the newline characters. What are you wanting to make your set from? Lines? Words?

Comment: One word on each line.Each line should be a new entry in set.

Comment: Sorry, actually `re.sub('\n$', '', ...)` will not change the input. So that just leaves it as dead (and misleading) code.

Comment: Well then: after you've created `installed_packages`, what does `repr(installed_packages)` look like?

Comment: (I say `installed_packages` rather than `installedPackages` because [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) would like you to name your variables thus, please.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip Chris.  `repr(installed_packages)` a sample of what it returns is "nzeitgeist-core\nzeitgeist-datahub\nzenity\nzenity-common\nzip\nzlib1g\nzlib1g:i386\nzlib1g-dev" I tried using `set(repr(installed_packages))` and that didn't work. Also, `re.sub('\n$', '', ...)` is supposed to remove a blank line at the end of the string.

Comment: @Poweruser32: hmm, missed that portion. In such a case you would use `rstrip('\n')`.

Comment: Oh sorry I think I misinterpreted you. `re.sub('\n$', '',` will remove the empty line but `re.sub('\n$', '', re.sub('install$', '', re.sub('\t', '', stdout), 0,re.MULTILINE))` removes tabs and the word install at the end of each line as well. raw stdoutput is "zlib1g-dev                         install" that line strips it down to just "zlib1g-dev". Thank you fo rthe rstrip function tip too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following?

**Edit:** after several iterations:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

DEBUG = True
if DEBUG:
    def log(msg, data):
        print(msg)
        print(repr(data))
else:
    def log(msg, data):
        pass

def setFromFile(fname):
    with open(fname) as inf:
        return set(ln.strip() for ln in inf)

def setFromString(s):
    return set(ln.strip() for ln in s.split("\n"))

def main():
    # get list of installed packages
    p = Popen(['dpkg', '--get-selections'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
    installed_packages = setFromString(stdout)

    # get list of expected packages
    known_packages = setFromFile('/home/john/packages.txt')

    # calculate the difference
    unknown_packages = installed_packages - known_packages
    unknown_packages_string = "\n".join(unknown_packages)

    log("Installed packages:", installed_packages)
    log("Known packages:", known_packages)
    log("Unknown packages:", unknown_packages)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Sorry I just started to learn python today. I do not understand why I would get an indentation error.`File "test.py", line 16
    installed_packages = setFromString(stdout)
                                             ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level`

Comment: I unindented the main() function, but now it is saying stdout is not defined. `installed_packages = setFromString(stdout)
NameError: name 'stdout' is not defined`

Comment: @Poweruser32: I've included the subprocess creation, if you set the name of your script properly it ought to work.

Comment: I tried this. http://pastebin.com/TnStVk5w and it just gives me the raw output of the dpkg command i give it.

Comment: @Poweruser32: try printing installed_packages and known_packages, make sure they are populating correctly? If known_packages is empty, unknown_packages will be identical to installed_packages (which sounds like what you are describing).

Comment: Ah thank you so much!! I edited the answer to show the code I used. I just had to remove the tabs and "install" from the end of each line from installed_packages. ex You can not subtract 'sample-package\t\t\t\t install' from 'sample-package' Now is there anyways to get unknown_packages back to a string? str() doesnt work

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write to a string buffer file-like use [`StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html)

```
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> installed_packages = StringIO()
>>> installed_packages.write('test')
>>> installed_packages.getvalue()
'test'
```

Comment: installed_packages.getvalue() produces what I want, but "print set(installed_packages.getvalue())" returns set(['\n', '+', '-', '.', '1', '0', '3', '2', '5', '4', '7', '6', '9', '8', ':', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'e', 'd', 'g', 'f', 'i', 'h', 'k', 'j', 'm', 'l', 'o', 'n', 'q', 'p', 's', 'r', 'u', 't', 'w', 'v', 'y', 'x', 'z'])

Comment: If the user controls the code, StringIO is often not appropriate. Its main useful spot is where there is code which is expecting a file object and *can't* be changed easily. It sounds in this case like the @Poweruser32 is just wanting to switch from files to strings.

Answer (score 1):

The set data type takes an iterable as a parameter, therefore if installedPackages a string with multiple items you need to split it by the delimiter.  For example, the following code would split the string by all commas:

```
for line in set(installedPackages.split(',')) - set(b):
    c.write(line)
```

Comment: I just tried "for line in set(installedPackages.split('\n')) - set(b):" and it produces no output

Comment: Edit your question to show the code where you assign the string to installedPackages.